# Collection view cell vertical top alignment

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a problem in collection view(Grid Format) cell height. The grid format contains two columns overall, so basically 2 cells in each row. My collection view cell height increase according to the content inside it but the content is center aligned and not top aligned. I want to achieve the height of the cells in a row which has the greater height. How can I do that? Please advice.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B56cE4V6JI-RYmdQT2pIZ0hYQ2phM3Z2YmJNYU1SeXNnYTNN/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B56cE4V6JI-RQUdqVmV4b244cFI5SGd2TnJfbG1tckdQU21Z/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B56cE4V6JI-RYTYxVzJyVUp1clpJTkVqYjN6QXBPeERvVHZR/view?usp=sharing

I have added a link above which is the problem right now.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        let cellsAcross: CGFloat = 2
        let spaceBetweenCells: CGFloat = 10
        let dim = (collectionView.bounds.width - (cellsAcross - 1) * spaceBetweenCells) / cellsAcross
        print(dim) // calculating width
        //calculating my content height
        let toppingHeight = sizeOfString(string: PizzaMenuItems[indexPath.row].pizzaToppings, constrainedToWidth: Double(dim))
        let pizzaNameHeight = sizeOfString(string: PizzaMenuItems[indexPath.row].menuName, constrainedToWidth: Double(dim))
        let newHeight = toppingHeight.height + pizzaNameHeight.height + 57
        // to increase my collection view height
        let heightt = (view.frame.width)/2
        let count = self.PizzaMenuItems.count
        if self.PizzaMenuItems.count == 1 {
        }
        else{
            if count % 2 == 0
            { //even Number
                collectionViewC_Height.constant =  heightt  *  CGFloat(self.PizzaMenuItems.count/2) + 57
            }  else
            {  // odd Number
                collectionViewC_Height.constant =  heightt  *  CGFloat(self.PizzaMenuItems.count/2+1)}
        }
        return CGSize(width: dim, height:  newHeight)}
```

Comment: You can precalculate all of the heights for each cells, and check the row+1 or row -1 according to odds or now, and use the max for the height of the cell ?

Answer (score 0):

Verbal work around:

1. In your collection cell xib don't specify UILabel on the container view.
2. place a UIView on the bottom layer of container view with (top:0,lead:0,trail:0,bottom:0) constraints.
3. Now place your UILabel with constraints (top:0,lead:0,trail:0,height:<=UIView)
4. This helps you to adjust your label height according to their content which help to anchor label alignment on top.